# Flutter The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
I didn't understand how to solve this.

```
 @override
Future<List<Users>?> getAllUsers() async {
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await firestore.collection("users").get();
List<Users> allUsers = [];

allUsers = querySnapshot.docs.map((e) => Users.fromMap(e.data())).toList();
return allUsers;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> querySnapshot = await firestore.collection("users").get();
```

Comment: this solved my problem, thank youuu

Comment: make sure you click the check mark if the problem is solved